# PHP won't recognize PUT/POST Request sent via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send POST and PUT Requests via jQuery to a PHP application. The index.php is my controller which checks the $_SERVER["REQUESTED_METHOD"] and works as a dispatcher. For example: if a GET request is sent, my index.php sends back the rendered view of the main page.

Now I want to implement some more request methods, like PUT and POST. But none of them are working properly. My index.php always behaves like a GET was sent.

When I send a request via POSTMAN, the index.php response is correct. Also a POST request via plain HTML (method="post" action="index.php") works correctly.

In Chrome DevTools the correct request headers were displayed when I send the request via jQuery. But in $_SERVER[] request method "GET" is shown.

index.php

```php
<?php

// CONSTANTS
define('ROOT', str_replace("public", "", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));

// INCLUDES
require_once(ROOT . "core/Authenticator.php");
require_once(ROOT . "model/User.php");
require_once(ROOT . "model/ShoppingList.php");
require_once(ROOT . "views/Lists.php");



if(Authenticator::checkAuthentication()) {

    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    Utility::debug($method);

    switch ($method) {
        case 'GET':
            Lists::render();
            break;
        case 'POST':
            Print("POST");
            break;
        case 'PUT':
            Print("PUT");
            break;
        case 'DELETE':
            print("DELETE");
            break;
        default:
            print("DEFAULT");
            break;
    }

} else {

    header("Location: login.php");
    die();

}
```

script.js

```js
/* global $*/

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(processArticle);
});


function processArticle() {

    let data = {};
    data.article = "article";
    data.id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        method: "PUT",
        url: "index.php",
        data: data
    });
};
```

Comment: where `Authenticator::checkAuthentication()` function is defined? seems like it always fails and `else` condition executed every-time

Comment: checkAuthentication() is defined in Authenticator class and works fine. The authenticator class handles the $_SESSION of the user. I've already tried without user authentication, but the problem still occurs. I guess the problem is somewhere related to the javascript part, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: change your jQuery code to this and try:- `$(document).ready(function () {
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {

  let data = {};
  data.article = "article";
  data.id = $(this).attr('id');

  $.ajax({
   method: "PUT",
   url: "index.php",
   data: data
  });
 });
});`

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I tried your code, but it's the same result. A correct PUT request was sent, but still no correct processing on the PHP side.